# Is there any way to refresh templatepanel in guidewire or whole page refresh?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

We have integrated google map in guidewire claimcenter. The functionality is when we receive address from contactmanager then the google maps will display respective address. Now the problem is if we again search it with any new parameters and if we receive new address it is not getting updated. If I update the browser then it is getting reflected. Is there any way we can refresh it from templatepanel or refresh whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try utilizing `PostOnChange` for the contact/address field.

Comment: I tried. But it didn't work